# Why my Process terminate?

Tags: java, multithreading, process

I have a Runnable object, that runs a ping operation -

```
Runnable r1 = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try{
                    List<String> commands = new ArrayList<String>();
                    commands.add("ping");
                    commands.add("-c");
                    commands.add("10");
                    commands.add("google.com");

                    System.out.println("Before process");
                    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(commands);
                    Process process = builder.start();

                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
                    String line = null;
                    while ((line=reader.readLine()) != null){
                        System.out.println(line);
                    }
                    process.waitFor();
                    System.out.println("After process");

                }catch (Exception ex){
                   ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
```

If I launch this in current thread like this:

```
r1.run();
```

I get this output:

```
Before process
PING google.com (173.194.32.33): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 173.194.32.33: icmp_seq=0 ttl=53 time=34.857 ms
64 bytes from 173.194.32.33: icmp_seq=1 ttl=53 time=39.550 ms
64 bytes from 173.194.32.33: icmp_seq=2 ttl=53 time=44.212 ms
64 bytes from 173.194.32.33: icmp_seq=3 ttl=53 time=38.111 ms
64 bytes from 173.194.32.33: icmp_seq=4 ttl=53 time=39.622 ms
64 bytes from 173.194.32.33: icmp_seq=5 ttl=53 time=41.391 ms
64 bytes from 173.194.32.33: icmp_seq=6 ttl=53 time=41.280 ms
64 bytes from 173.194.32.33: icmp_seq=7 ttl=53 time=39.645 ms
64 bytes from 173.194.32.33: icmp_seq=8 ttl=53 time=35.931 ms
64 bytes from 173.194.32.33: icmp_seq=9 ttl=53 time=38.245 ms

--- google.com ping statistics ---
10 packets transmitted, 10 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 34.857/39.284/44.212/2.575 ms
After process
```

But if I run it in a new thread like this:

```
    Thread thread = new Thread(r1);
    thread.start();
```

I get this:

```
Before process
```

Why are the outputs different?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you run in separate thread, your main thread will probably finish before, so your `r1` will not have enough time to finish. If you start in current thread you will wait until finish. Try to add `thread.join()` after start and see what is happening.

Comment: Or add `thread.setDaemon(false)` before start. This will prevent the new thread from stopping when main thread terminates.